# PowerBuilder 12 Client runtime

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I am using PowerBuilder 12 for one of the application. I have deployed the project as an exe. But when i run the exe in a client machine it asks for some PB dlls. Is there any PowerBuilder client 12 runtime available for this, or is there a different way to deploy the exe.

Thanks

Arvind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **need** the deployment DLLs, no matter what kind of target you've created. However, which deployment DLLs you need depends on what kind of target you've created and what features you're using. The guide to determining which DLLs you need is the "Application Techniques" manual, particularly the "Packaging an Application for Deployment" and "Deploying Applications and Components" chapters. This manual (and others) came on your software distribution media (CDs, download), but they are also available at http://sybooks.sybase.com; they are available to view online or to download as PDFs.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have missed the dll's and would have given the .exe alone. This is because when you compile and build libraries, your application gets ready. You just drop your compiled files into the folder containing the .exe file. Moreover, PB has specific runtime dll's which are by default present. Check your files, you might have missed the dll's.